# Android: Sharing app content to a web page

Tags: android, web, sharing

I want my app users to be able to share one of the app pages to others as an external web link as a good marketing strategy, so people who don't have the app can view this page and get excited hopefully to download and register although no one can view the app without signed in, for now I have the app and its web domain I didn't build the website yet, What is the efficient way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some code on the server to receive the data, store it and then serve it back (php/mysql or java or anything else). The easiest way to do it is to make a form and to send a request from the android app to simulate a filled-in form.
You could also just publish to Facebook or Google+, there are APIs to do that from and Android app.

Comment: I just wanna display this page and its one of the application custom pages APIs can't help, any ways Thank You :)

Comment: You could take a screenshot and post a bitmap (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android).